# How to replace a pattern in a string?

Tags: python, regex, replace

Hi I am trying to replace all the expressions containing 'www...' and 'http://..' with just 'URL'. I tried this but I am getting this error.

`TypeError: expected string or buffer`

My code is:

`df['text_1'] = re.sub('((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','URL',df['text'])`

`df[text]` contains tweets, so I want to keep only the text in there.
I am in Python 2
Thanks.

Comment: Is `df[text]` a _list_ of tweets, i.e. a list of strings, or a single string? Have you tried `... = [re.sub('<regex>','URL',s) for s in df['text']]`?

Comment: in each value of `df[text]` there is one tweet. This is what are you asking?

Comment: Please clarify what data type `df` actually is. We know it's not a string and not a buffer, I'm assuming it's a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: yes it is DataFrame, would you recommend me where can I read more about these differences? String, DataFrames and Buffer? Now I am a bit confuse about this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `df` is a pandas DataFrame, don't use `re.sub`. Use [pandas.DataFrame.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) instead:

```
df['text_1'] = df['text'].replace('((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))',
                                  'URL',
                                  regex=True)
```

This will generate a new column `text_1` with all values of `text` replaced according to your regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're getting that error because you're not supplying a `string or buffer` as the third argument to `re.sub`.

```
>>> re.sub('\W', 'REPLACED', 'this is my text')
'thisREPLACEDisREPLACEDmyREPLACEDtext'
>>> re.sub('\W', 'REPLACED', None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Ensure that `df['text']` contains a proper string before you try using it for `re.sub`

Comment: That worked, yes I am using dataframes, thanks everybody